# Remove/Add CSS class with js

Tags: javascript, css, addclass, removeclass

I want to remove and later add class to this part of code:

```
           <tr class="promo-tag">
                <td class="plan-za-razgovore-xs"></td>
                <td class="plan-za-razgovore-s"></td>
                <td class="promo plan-za-surfanje-m"></td>
                <td class="promo plan-za-surfanje-l"></td>
                <td class="promo plan-za-zabavu-xl"></td>
                <td class="promo plan-za-zabavu-xxl"></td>
                <td class="promo plan-za-mlade"></td>
            </tr>
```

I have the following script, I don't want to remove `.promo` class from all elements just from `.plan-za-surfanje-m`, and all the others keep the `.promo` class. I tried many variations of `$('something').removeClass('myClass')` but no success so far.

```
    if (vals.join('') === "mcd12True") {
    $('.promo-tag .promo .plan-za-surfanje-m').removeClass( 'promo' )
    & $('.promo-tag .promo').html('Promotivna cijena').val() 
    & $('.tarif-price .plan-za-surfanje-m').html('<h2> 95 </h2> <p> kn/mj<br> 12 mjeseci</p>').val()
    & $('.tarif-price .plan-za-surfanje-l').html('<h2> 135 </h2> <p> kn/mj<br> 12 mjeseci</p>').val()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a function for this, no need to complicate things:

```
$('.plan-za-surfanje-m').removeClass('promo')
```

Comment: This successfully removes promo class but why does this part of code: & `$('.promo-tag .promo').html('Promotivna cijena').val() ` still add text when there is no promo class?

Comment: Your selector is not formatted correctly. When you use a space in your selector, it will select all elements that contain either `promo-tag` or `promo`. To get the selector to select an element where both of them are present, remove the space.

Comment: But the thing is when I removed that space none of them got that text "Promotivna cijena". Why is that?
Sorry if my questions are stupid, but I'm still new in this and trying to learn.

Comment: My bad, I see the error now. You want to select the table row with class `promo-tag`, it looks like this:
`$('.promo-tag');`

You then want to select all children of this element with the class `promo`, and it looks like this:
`$('.promo-tag > .promo')`.

The full code you'd want to use is this:
`$('.promo-tag > .promo').html('Promotivna cijena')`

Comment: Tried that too. Did some research about CSS Selectors but still my class is being removed with this function, but other function still writes that extra text when there is no class .promo. Can't find any other solution so I used this `$('.plan-za-surfanje-m.promo').html('').val() `

Comment: It works as expected for me. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uegqfu01/1/).

Comment: Can you check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uegqfu01/5/)
Just try changing 24 mjeseci and 12 mjeseci, when 12 mjeseci is selected only "95 kn/mj" should be shown, without "Promotivna cijena" text

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for an element that has more than one class is wrong, it shouldn't have spaces. Try this instead.

```
 $('.promo-tag .promo.plan-za-surfanje-m').removeClass( 'promo' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
document.querySelector(".plan-za-surfanje-m").classList.toggle("promo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, you search `.plan-za-surfanje-m` in `.promo`, but it's the same element.

Replace

```
$('.promo-tag .promo .plan-za-surfanje-m').removeClass( 'promo' )
```

by

```
$('.promo-tag .promo.plan-za-surfanje-m').removeClass( 'promo' )
```

or

```
$('.promo-tag .plan-za-surfanje-m').removeClass( 'promo' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$('.promo-tag').find('td').removeClass('promo');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in `.promo` and `.plan-za-surfanje-m` you need remove it

```
$('.promo-tag .promo.plan-za-surfanje-m').removeClass( 'promo' )
```